# CS1501 No overload for method 'GetBlocks'

Tags: c#, pdfpig

I am using this code from pdfpig and I am getting the error

> CS1501 No overload for method 'GetBlocks'

Code:

```
using UglyToad.PdfPig;
using UglyToad.PdfPig.Content;
using UglyToad.PdfPig.DocumentLayoutAnalysis.PageSegmenter;
using UglyToad.PdfPig.DocumentLayoutAnalysis.WordExtractor;

using (PdfDocument document = PdfDocument.Open(@"C:\Temp\file.pdf"))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < document.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        var page = document.GetPage(i + 1);
        var words = page.GetWords();
        var blocks = DocstrumBoundingBoxes.Instance.GetBlocks(words,
                new DocstrumBoundingBoxes.DocstrumBoundingBoxesOptions()
                {
                    WithinLineBounds = new DocstrumBoundingBoxes.AngleBounds(-45, 45),
                    BetweenLineBounds = new DocstrumBoundingBoxes.AngleBounds(35, 170),
                    BetweenLineMultiplier = 1.5
                });

        foreach (var block in blocks)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

I referred to the wiki page and the code mentioned is the same
under this link
[Document-Layout-Analysis](https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig/wiki/Document-Layout-Analysis#docstrum-for-bounding-boxes-method)

How to resolve this error? I know `GetBlocks` can only take 1 argument, but the advanced case the same code is used:

```
var blocks = DocstrumBoundingBoxes.Instance.GetBlocks(words,
                new DocstrumBoundingBoxes.DocstrumBoundingBoxesOptions()
                {
                    WithinLineBounds = new DocstrumBoundingBoxes.AngleBounds(-45, 45),
                    BetweenLineBounds = new DocstrumBoundingBoxes.AngleBounds(35, 170),
                    BetweenLineMultiplier = 1.5
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project is still not in the release version, so the API can change, as mentioned in the [Migration to 0.1.6](https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig/wiki/Migration-to-0.1.6) guide:

> In summary methods such as `GetWords` and `GetBlocks` taking options arguments have changed to take the options in the class constructor.

You can try creating an instance and providing it the options instead of using a shared one:

```cs
var boxes = new DocstrumBoundingBoxes(new DocstrumBoundingBoxes.DocstrumBoundingBoxesOptions()
{
    WithinLineBounds = new DocstrumBoundingBoxes.AngleBounds(-45, 45),
    BetweenLineBounds = new DocstrumBoundingBoxes.AngleBounds(35, 170),
    BetweenLineMultiplier = 1.5
});
boxes.GetBlocks(words);
```